# Disable logs for solr healthchecks

Tags: solr, kubernetes

I'm currently running a distributed solr cloud with Kubernetes.

I have configured a liveness probe with kubernetes which always restarts the solr pod if the liveness probe fails.

```
solr healthckeck -c collection-name
```

This works very well, except that every time when a liveness probe gets performed, solr logs this request (currently 4 lines of log output). The liveness probe gets executed every 10 seconds, so the whole log file consists of this healthcheck messages and real useful messages disappear or can hardly be found.

Does anyone know if there is a way in solr to disable these healthcheck messages/logs?

Comment: What level are these messages logged on? Do you need other log messages on the same level? Solr uses log4j2 now, so you should be able to configure the log to skip the messages that originate with a specific prefix or message.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set up a filter on your Solr log4j2 configs:

Something like:

```
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <RegexFilter regex=".*something-that-matches-the-liveness-probe.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think the question was about keeping the liveness logs, but removing them from the logging - not the other way around :-)

Comment: Thanks! I just realized. Took my best shot at the answer :)